# Would removing the すること turn クリア back into a noun?

Tags: word-choice, compound-verbs

Hypothetically speaking, if こと is being used as a nominalizing suffix in the following sentence:

> その時々の課題をクリアすることに、全力で取り組んでいる間は、何も思い悩んだりせずにすむ。

would the above sentence be able to be re-written as the following?

> その時々の課題をクリアに、全力で取り組んでいる間は、何も思い悩んだりせずにすむ。

I'm asking this as I'm certain the こと is only there to nominalize the suru verb, which appears to be made of a noun-suru compound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

課題をクリアする means "to clear (succeed in solving) a problem". It takes an object (marked by を）問題. This is clearly a transitive verb structure. If you try and change it to a noun then you are left with 課題を and no verb to go with it.

Perhaps you meant to ask about 課題**の**クリアに. This would a least be grammatical, but I think it is also nonsense.
課題をクリアすることに取り組んでいる means "striving to clear (solve) the problem".
When you strive you strive to **do** something. It only makes sense to me that a verb is required.

Comment: You know, I was so focused on the hypothetical nominalization of the クリアすること part, the preceding を COMPLETLY slipped my mind. Having a laser focus mind is both a blessing and a curse when it comes to translating even hypothetical translations.